# Error in simple C# client using sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

I am trying to just create a very simple client/server in C#, basically all i am trying to do at the moment is get the client to connect to the server, which is where I get en error.  My server starts fine but when I try and start my client i get this error:

```
The requested address is not valid in this context
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Client.Client.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

The basic client I have right now goes as follows

```
        try
        {
            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0");
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 8001);

            Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            try
            {
                sender.Connect(remoteEP);                    

                Console.WriteLine("Connected to: " + remoteEP);

                byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Testing");

                sender.Send(msg);


                sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                sender.Close();

            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace);
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not a valid IP address.   For localhost (your own machine) this is what you want

```
   IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
```